# Joining multiple tables with multiple dates

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have a master table which is like this

```
customer_id  Customer_name
1             A
2             B
3             C
4             D
```

And I have multiple user activity tables. I am giving only an example of 2 such tables but there are like 20 such tables

**Table 1:**

```
customer_id     activity_date   No_of_likes
2                1/1/16          2
3                1/1/16          3
2                2/1/16          5
2                1/1/16          1
```

**Table 2:**

```
customer_id     activity_date   No_of_comments
2                1/1/16          1
4                5/1/16          7
2                6/1/16          2
```

And this is my final table which I need. I do not have a master calendar table, and I am not sure of a way to joining to get the below output

```
customer_id     activity_name   activity_date    quantity
1                -                  -              -
2               Likes             1/1/16            3
2               Likes             2/1/16            5
2               Comments          1/1/16            1
2               Comments          6/1/16            2
3               Likes             1/1/16            3
4               Comments          5/1/16            7
```

And I also need a output like this. I think coalesce solves the above but I am not sure how to do the below

```
  customer_id      activity_date    like_quantity    comment_activity 
     1                 -                -                     - 
     2                1/1/16            3                     1 
     2                2/1/16            5                     - 
     2                6/1/16            -                     2 
     3                1/1/16            3                     - 
     4                5/1/16            -                     7
```

Hope I was clear. Please help me with a SQL query for having this join

Comment: your question related mysql or sqlserver

Comment: I am sorry to add to this. What do i do if I need it like this ?

customer_id       activity_date    like_quantity      comment_activity
1                             -                    -                       -
2                       1/1/16                 3                      1
2                       2/1/16                 5                      -
2                       6/1/16                 -                       2        
3                       1/1/16                 3                      -
4                        5/1/16                -                       7

Comment: Is it SQL Server or mySQL then? Anyway, look up PIVOT operator (or pivoting in general, depending on your RDBMS)..

Comment: Why not have 1 'activity' table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

Using `UNION` and `LEFT JOIN` you can accomplish this.

```
SELECT 
  your_master_table.customer_id,
  COALESCE(t.activity_name,'-') AS activity_name,
  COALESCE(t.activity_date,'-') AS activity_date,
  COALESCE(t.quantity,'-') AS quantity
FROM your_master_table

LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    customer_id,
    activity_date,
    No_of_likes AS quantity,
    'Likes' AS activity_name
    FROM TABLE_1

    UNION 

    SELECT 
    customer_id,
    activity_date,
    No_of_comments AS quantity,
    'Comments' AS activity_name
    FROM TABLE_2

) AS t
ON your_master_table.customer_id = t.customer_id
ORDER BY your_master_table.customer_id;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57e88/1/0)

Running the above query on your sample input you will get the following output:

**Output**:

```
| customer_id | activity_name | activity_date | quantity |
|-------------|---------------|---------------|----------|
|           1 |             - |             - |        - |
|           2 |      Comments |    2016-01-01 |        1 |
|           2 |      Comments |    2016-01-06 |        2 |
|           2 |         Likes |    2016-01-01 |        2 |
|           2 |         Likes |    2016-01-02 |        5 |
|           2 |         Likes |    2016-01-01 |        1 |
|           3 |         Likes |    2016-01-01 |        3 |
|           4 |      Comments |    2016-01-05 |        7 |
```

**EDIT:**

***Based on the change in your requirement***

```
SELECT 
your_master_table.customer_id,
COALESCE(DATE_FORMAT(t.activity_date,'%d/%m/%y'),'-') AS activity_date,
COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN t.activity_name = 'Likes' THEN t.quantity END),'-') AS like_quantity,
COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN t.activity_name = 'Comments' THEN t.quantity END),'-') AS comment_activity
FROM your_master_table

LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    customer_id,
    activity_date,
    No_of_likes AS quantity,
    'Likes' AS activity_name
    FROM TABLE_1

    UNION 

    SELECT 
    customer_id,
    activity_date,
    No_of_comments AS quantity,
    'Comments' AS activity_name
    FROM TABLE_2

) AS t
ON your_master_table.customer_id = t.customer_id
GROUP BY your_master_table.customer_id,t.activity_date
ORDER BY your_master_table.customer_id;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57e88/6/0)

Comment: answer is good logic, but add date related condition to match the proper result

Comment: I didn't get this **add date related condition to match the proper result**. Please explain @Ajay2707

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had a change of mind and I need the table like this 
customer_id       activity_date    like_quantity      comment_activity
1                             -                    -                       -
2                       1/1/16                 3                      1
2                       2/1/16                 5                      -
2                       6/1/16                 -                       2        
3                       1/1/16                 3                      -
4                        5/1/16                -                       7

Comment: Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` ;).

Comment: It wont remove it as its a different activity and I dont want data to be deleted

Comment: Thanks @1000111 for the edits and the answer. I have added a last part to my question, it would be great if you could help me do that too ?

Comment: Please check the updated answer. Find the modified query under **EDIT** section of my answer. @VinolJoyD'souza

Comment: Thanks @1000111 .. Your answer did help me a lot. Just wondering if there was a way to doit just by using left join to each table ?

Comment: No this not the ideal case to get the desired output using `LEFT JOIN`. @VinolJoyD'souza

Comment: Thanks for the timely help. Appreciate it

Comment: Please always practice marking answer as [**ACCEPTED**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it works for you. So that others find it useful. @VinolJoyD'souza